# View DDL of Insert Row from IDE

Tags: datagrip

Is there a way to see the DDL that would be executed from the table editing view within DataGrip? I don't have enough reputation to post an image but the view I'm talking about is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHhYj.png).

What I'm looking to do is to be able to copy the DDL from various operations in the IDE and use them where I may need them in scripts and what-not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the table
Table editor
Then in the bottom you can see to tabs Data and DDL (default is data)
Click ddl for ddl script ;)